# initializer_list<T> assignment operator requirement on T

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I am wondering if an  `initializer_list<T>` requires that T has an assignment operator. The following

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete;
};

std::vector<Foo> f = { Foo( ), Foo( ) };
```

compiles on clang 3.4.2 but fails on Visual Studo 2013 with a `"error C2280: 'Foo &Foo::operator =(const Foo &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function"`. I am assuming clang is correct here but wanted to check that there is no requirement for T to to be assignable.

Answer (score 6):

`std::initializer_list<T>` does not require `T` to be assignable in any way, because copying `std::initializer_list` objects is shallow - it does not copy the underlying data.

You're getting the error because MSVC 2013 (and below) does not support automatic generation of move constructors and move assignment operators. So the error actually comes from `std::vector` trying to copy from the initializer list, not from the initializer list itself.

It's still a question why the error is triggered, since the `std::vector` constructor taking `std::initializer_list` only requires the type to be `EmplaceConstructible` and possibly `MoveInsertable`, neither of which uses assignments.

Comment: Very interesting, when you say "automatic generation of move constructor" do you mean in the std::initializer_list itself or on the T type. I tried Fooas follows struct Foo
{
    Foo( ) { }

    Foo( const Foo& ) { }
    Foo( Foo&& ) { }

    Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete;
    Foo& operator=( Foo&& ) = delete;
};

Comment: @goneskiing I meant in the `Foo` type (in any user-defined class type, really). Of course, it applies to `std::initializer_list` too, but there, as library authors, they can get around it by defining the move operations explicitly. Not that they need to; as I said, `std::initializer_list` is a shallow wrapper (probably just two pointers internally).

Comment: So when I explicitly add a move constructor to Foo I still get an error, I assume this means the VS 2013 initilizer_list is messed up. I did try VS 14 CTP 3 and that works with the origional Foo

Comment: @goneskiing Or their `std::vector` is messed up. You can try just playing around with `std::initializer_list` without ever passing it to a `std` container, and/or using a different container (such as `std::list` which never needs to move its items around).

Comment: std::list works as does a stand alone std::initializer_list so you are probably right about std::vector. Thanks, std::list is a good work around for me.